# Vertx + OpenAPI + OAuth2 security handler is calling twice

Tags: oauth-2.0, vert.x, openapi

I'm a newbie in vertx world. I used this link for setting up my openapi routing: https://gist.github.com/slinkydeveloper/bdf5929c2506988d78fc08205089409a

Here is my sources:

### api.yaml

```
#other endpoints...
/api/v1/protected/verification:
post:
  summary: Summary
  operationId: verification
  security:
    - ApiKey: []
  tags:
    - verification
  responses:
    '200':
      description: User details
      content:
        application/json:
          schema:
            $ref: "#/components/schemas/User"
    '401':
      description: Unauthorized

    default:
      description: unexpected error
      content:
        application/json:
          schema:
            $ref: "#/components/schemas/Exception"
#other endpoints ....
components:
  securitySchemes:
   ApiKey:
    type: apiKey
    name: Authorization
    in: header
#other ones
```

### OpenApi setup

```
OpenAPI3RouterFactory.createRouterFactoryFromFile(vertx, "src/main/resources/api.yaml") { openAPI3RouterFactoryAsyncResult ->
        if (openAPI3RouterFactoryAsyncResult.succeeded()) {
            // Spec loaded with success
            val routerFactory = openAPI3RouterFactoryAsyncResult.result()
            val keycloakJson = JsonObject("{\n" +
                    "\"realm\": \"master\",\n" +
                    "\"bearer-only\": true,\n" +
                    "\"auth-server-url\": \"http://localhost:8080/auth\",\n" +
                    "\"ssl-required\": \"external\",\n" +
                    "\"realm-public-key\": \"MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAn9Xya697ZVZzQidld4uCwRoWmLyWBDQQhn+EL1e0WDUWq9v39OBpM+HadkYlOMvfU1A8ohGZZVBkKV4w35gkm3bFPluCPsWxdcqD1NNF6BnIC6bRicgP/4beeehff8nWI3mFAfH7Q7Ik8mm8BDQYhOPRx50JBkDiIQ7AlAjNJ+5/eIj6Pt/eZSmMSk+vM4Xu64E0mCZfHpasdf!QsFGN+VPQejNBz7h9nEdi3swIIo0ot2+5PZGELX/2Dek7cY4RMKGb+rvU6ug3UvZHQ985KuubKsWMCs8+A80yWSoA6umw1DC5rAmc5jo/6giWawuFj5jFZRx69CcMSx1VaEJ5lS4LmAi5sXuQIDAQAB\",\n" +
                    "\"resource\": \"vertx\",\n" +
                    "\"use-resource-role-mappings\": true,\n" +
                    "\"credentials\": {\n" +
                    "\"secret\": \"asd1t747-3d11-456f-a553-d8e140cfaf58\"\n" +
                    "}\n" +
                    "}")
            val oauth2 = KeycloakAuth
                    .create(vertx, OAuth2FlowType.AUTH_CODE, keycloakJson)
            val handler = OAuth2AuthHandler.create(oauth2,
                    "http://localhost:8081/")
            routerFactory.addSecurityHandler("ApiKey", handler)

            handler?.setupCallback(routerFactory.router.route("/callback"))

            routerFactory.addHandlerByOperationId(EndpointUriOperationId.SIGN_UP.endpoint, { routingContext -> signUpRouter?.signUp(routingContext) })
            routerFactory.addHandlerByOperationId(EndpointUriOperationId.SIGN_IN.endpoint, { routingContext -> signInRouter?.signIn(routingContext) })
            routerFactory.addHandlerByOperationId(EndpointUriOperationId.CONFIRM_ACCESS_CODE.endpoint, { routingContext -> signUpRouter?.confirmAccessCode(routingContext) })
            routerFactory.addHandlerByOperationId(EndpointUriOperationId.IS_EMAIL_EXISTS.endpoint, { routingContext -> signUpRouter?.isEmailExists(routingContext) })
            routerFactory.addHandlerByOperationId(EndpointUriOperationId.GET_ACCESS_CODE.endpoint, { routingContext -> signUpRouter?.getAccessCode(routingContext) })
            routerFactory.addHandlerByOperationId(EndpointUriOperationId.VERIFICATION.endpoint, { routingContext -> signInRouter?.verification(routingContext) })

            // Add an handler with a combination of HttpMethod and path
            // Before router creation you can enable or disable mounting a default failure handler for ValidationException

            // Now you have to generate the router

            val router = routerFactory.router
            router.route().handler(CorsHandler.create("*")
                    .allowedMethod(HttpMethod.GET)
                    .allowedMethod(HttpMethod.DELETE)
                    .allowedMethod(HttpMethod.POST)
                    .allowedMethod(HttpMethod.PUT)
                    .allowedMethod(HttpMethod.PATCH)
                    .allowedHeader("Authorization")
                    .allowedHeader("user-agent")
                    .allowedHeader("Access-Control-Request-Method")
                    .allowedHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials")
                    .allowedHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin")
                    .allowedHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers")
                    .allowedHeader("Content-Type")
                    .allowedHeader("Content-Length")
                    .allowedHeader("X-Requested-With")
                    .allowedHeader("x-auth-token")
                    .allowedHeader("Location")
                    .exposedHeader("Location")
                    .exposedHeader("Content-Type")
                    .exposedHeader("Content-Length")
                    .exposedHeader("ETag")
                    .maxAgeSeconds(60))
            // Now you can use your Router instance
            val server = vertx.createHttpServer(HttpServerOptions().setPort(8081).setHost("0.0.0.0"))
            server.requestHandler(router::accept).listen()
            print("server is run\n")
        } else {
            // Something went wrong during router factory initialization
            val exception = openAPI3RouterFactoryAsyncResult.cause()
            print("OpenApiRoutingError! $exception")
        }
    }
```

### My verification endpoint

```
fun verification(routingContext: RoutingContext) {
    val map = (routingContext.user() as AccessTokenImpl).accessToken().map
    val username = map.get("preferred_username").toString()
    vertx.eventBus().send(SignInHandlerChannel.VERIFICATION.value(), username, { reply: AsyncResult<Message<String>> ->
        if (reply.succeeded()) {
            val result = JsonUtils.toPojo<MultiPosResponse<VerificationMapper>>(reply.result().body().toString())
            routingContext
                    .response()
                    .putBrowserHeaders()
                    .setStatusCode(result.code!!)
                    .end(result.toJson())
        } else{
            routingContext
                    .response()
                    .putBrowserHeaders()
                    .setStatusCode(HttpResponseStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.code())
                    .end(reply.cause().toString())
        }
    })
}
```

The problem is when I send request to "/api/v1/protected/verification" endpoint my oauth2 handler works twice. First request processes by oauth handler(as must be) then passed to next, to my endpoint handler after that for some reason request passed to oauth2 handler again(as I think it shouldn't be). How can I fix this problem?

Comment: You should use the upstream package (the package described in this gists was only for testing purpose). The package name is vertx-web-api-contract and you can find the docs here: http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-web-api-contract/java/

Comment: I did by documentation. And here is row in my build.gradle `compile io.vertx:vertx-web-api-contract:3.5.0`. What is wrong?

Comment: Maybe you are affected from bug https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-web/pull/739 Please try to debug doing multiple requests at same time. If any npe or similar were thrown, you are affected. Or try to clone the git repo of vertx web https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-web and do mvn install, then change version to 3.5.1-SNAPSHOT. This bug is fixed and will be in 3.5.1

Comment: Problem is solved. Thanx a lot. I have changed parseCredentials method in OAuth2AuthHandlerImpl.